# Выбор элемента из табличной части в документе 1С

Tags: 1с

С программированием и конфигурированием 1с знакома очень далеко.

Есть справочник услуг, который имеет табличные части:
1) Необходимые товары - хранит в себе список товаров, которые необходимы для услуги.
2) Выборочные товары - хранит в себе информацию о товарах, один из которых можно выбрать для данной услуги.

В 1С есть какая-то возможность, при которой при выборе элемента из одного справочника в другой колонке можно выбрать только те элементы, которые связаны с ним из другого справочника (не помню точно. буду благодарна, если напомните).

Есть ли возможность такая же возможность вывода списка товаров из табличной части и соответственно выбор отдельного элемента в табличной части?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходим более точный анализ этих справочников.
1. Если второй справочник подчинен первому, тогда необходимо использовать "УстановитьВладельца"
см http://1c-h.ru/2010/08/13/svyaz-po-vladelcu/
2. Если справочники независимые, можно программно выбрать необходимые данные с помощью запроса и добавить в "СписокВыбора"
см https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:3565:hdoc

Также необходимо учитывать какие ***формы*** используются в данном случае: обычные или управляемые

Comment: Это помогло бы, но у меня услуга находится в табличной части. Соответственно список из товаров нужно добавлять в выделенную строку в определенную ячейку.